# How to solve equation of arctangent within tangent?

Tags: trigonometry, algebraic-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

## Context

I found the $y = 1-\tan^2(2x-1)$ formula based on observations of equirectangular projections of a grid sphere. In order to transform spherical coordinates as $(lat,lon)$ to a quadrant of an equirectangular projection $(x,y)$, I need to solve the problem below.

## Problem

I have these equations for $x$ and $y$ with a given $lat$ and $lon$. Both $lat$ and $lon$ are normalized from $0$ to $1$. The first step is to remove $y$ and solve for $x$:

Eq. 1:
$$
    y = 1 - lat - lat\tan^2(\arctan(\sqrt{\frac{1}{lat}-1}) (2x-1) )
$$
Eq. 2:
$$
    y = 1 - lon - lon\tan^2(\arctan(\sqrt{\frac{1}{lon}-1}) (2x-2) )
$$

Removing $y$ from the equation (but I'm not sure if I'm going in the right direction with this):

Eq. 3:
$$
      lat + lat\tan^2(\arctan(\sqrt{\frac{1}{lat}-1}) (2x-1) )
$$
$$
    = lon + lon\tan^2(\arctan(\sqrt{\frac{1}{lon}-1}) (2x-2) )
$$

*EDIT*: With the help of a friend, I've been able to further reduce it to:

Eq. 4:
$$
    \frac
    {\cos(\arctan(\sqrt{\frac{1}{lon}-1}) (2x-2))}
    {\cos(\arctan(\sqrt{\frac{1}{lat}-1}) (2x-1))}
    = \sqrt{\frac{lon}{lat}}
$$

using this rule: $1+tan^2 = 1/cos^2$.

**And then I'm still stuck...** Any help is greatly appreciated!

Mind that the only interesting solution for $x$ is in the range $0 \le x \le 1$.

I've read something about [Law of Tangents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_tangents), but I'm not sure if I can apply it here, and if so, how?

---

## Example

For example, for a $lat$ of $\frac{40}{90}$ and a $lon$ of $\frac{120}{180}$, the intersection that I'm looking for is $x = 0.8756$ and $y=0.3175$. The graph including the intersection that can be found is [shown here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/d2ceativ4r):

[image: Intersection between the lat and lon functions]

---

*Note: I come from StackOverflow - not much of a mathematician - therefore I'm not sure if I got the tags and formatting right.*